# Como guardar uma mensagem de erro em uma string no R?

Tags: r

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que guarda a mensagem de erro de uma expressão em uma string.

Por exemplo eu gostaria de obter o resultado abaixo:

```
erro <- pegaErro(runif("a"))
erro
Error in runif("a") : invalid arguments
In addition: Warning message:
In runif("a") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Ou seja, o objeto `erro` fosse uma string com a mensagem de erro.

Tenho dois motivos para querer fazer isso:

- meu código é longo e produz diversas mensagens de erro, eu gostaria de guardar todas para olhar depois
- a mensagem de erro da minha função é muito grande e o console está
  cortando.

Comment: Da uma olhada no help do `try` e `tryCatch`. Acredito que eles devam servir para o que tu quer. Só cuidado que tu nos mandou 2 tipos de mensagem: uma de erro e outra de aviso (warning), são coisas diferentes.

Comment: @Rcoster era isso mesmo! vc não quer colocar na resposta?

Comment: Não quis enviar como resposta porque não domino direito essas funções, preferi dar a chance para alguém explicar melhor que eu, assim aprendo tb!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `geterrmessage()` retorna a última mensagem de erro. Se você não quer nada muito estruturado nem eficiente, é possível fazer uma gambiarra rápida que vai acumulando todas as mensagens de erro em um vetor.

Defina como opção quando tiver um erro:

```
options(error= expression(ifelse(exists("erros"), 
                                 erros <<- c(erros, geterrmessage()), 
                                 erros <<- geterrmessage())))
```

Aí rode o seu script. Por exemplo:

```
1 + "a"
runif("a")
funcaoquenaoexiste()
```

Ao final você terá um vetor chamado `erros` com todas as mensagens:

```
cat(erros)
 Error in 1 + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
 Error in runif("a") : invalid arguments
 Error: could not find function "funcaoquenaoexiste"
```

Depois que você fizer o que precisa, volte os erros ao normal com:

```
options(error= NULL)
```

Outra opção "gambiarra" é usar o knitr. Escreva seu script com markdown no knitr com a opção `error=TRUE` e ao final você terá tudo salvo em um documento HTML.

Se você quer algo mais estruturado e personalizado, terá que partir para o `try` ou `tryCatch`, como rcoster falou. Por exemplo, a função `try` vai salvar a mensagem de erro caso a expressão não seja executada corretamente:

```
resultado <- try(runif("a"))
resultado
[1] "Error in runif(\"a\") : invalid arguments\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in runif("a"): invalid arguments>
```

Há coisas mais elaboradas nas [resposas a essa pergunta do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function)

O Hadley tem o [pacote evaluate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evaluate/index.html), que talvez também sirva para o que você está querendo fazer:

```
library(evaluate)
erro <- evaluate('runif("a")')
str(erro)
List of 3
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ src: chr "runif(\"a\")"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "source"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ message: chr "NAs introduced by coercion"
  ..$ call   : language runif("a")
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleWarning" "warning" "condition"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ message: chr "invalid arguments"
  ..$ call   : language runif("a")
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "simpleError" "error" "condition"
```

Note que ele pegou tanto a mensagem de warning quanto a de erro.  A mensagem de erro é o terceiro elemento da lista:

```
erro[[3]]
<simpleError in runif("a"): invalid arguments>

erro[[3]]$message
[1] "invalid arguments"
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma que pode ser útil é encapsular a sua função envolta da função `safely` do pacote `purrr`.

Uma função encapsulada em `safely` retorna sempre uma lista com dois elementos: o resultado e o erro.

Exemplo:

```
new_function <- function(x){
  x + 1
}
new_safe_function <- safely(new_function)

new_safe_function("a")

# $result
# NULL
# 
# $error
# <simpleError in x + 1: non-numeric argument to binary operator>
```